# SNMP4J : looking for vendors compatible with SNMP V3 AES 256 implementation

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I understand SNMP V3 AES256 is non-standard. But SNMP4J seems to include a support of SNMP V3, including AES256. So it might work only for some vendors, some devices. 
Does anybody has already successfully tested it upon a device ? And which one ? Is there an official list somewhere ?

Thank you for your help !
Best regards,

Comment: It would be impossible to find an "official" list if it is not standardised.

Comment: Ok, but it has been implemented to be compatible with some devices. I am sure it must have been tested upon some of them. I only guess if some are listed somewhere.